# Java 8 collections streaming - Convert list to Set, transforming result

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Imaging object with following method:

```
class A { List<B> getIds(){...} }
```

Now I have an Collection of A as input;
And I want to get set of unique Ids out of it, normally you would go for:

```
Set<B> ids = new HashSet<>();
for(A a : input){
  ids.addAll(a.getIds());
}
```

Is there a way to do the same in one line using stream API, like following

```
Set<List<B>> set = input.stream().map((a) -> a.getIds()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but making flat set of B

Comment: Why is question marked as a duplicate? I know the question and answers are very similar, but a Set and List are not the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `flatMap`

```
input.stream()
    .map(a -> a.getIds())
    .flatMap(ids -> ids.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This will produce flat Set.

Comment: You can also use method reference: `.map(A::getIds).flatMap(List::stream)`

Comment: Just a single step `.flatMap(a -> a.getIds().stream())`…

Comment: It is better to use four `map` then one `map` with `map(a -> a.b().c().d().e())`